# Start a background service on boot in Oreo

Tags: android, service, background-process, android-8.0-oreo

I have a very specific use case. I need to start a background service that runs a web server on boot in Android 8. Can anyone recommend a way to achieve this? (In Android O).

It seems that you can't start a background service on boot anymore... Is there another way of doing it? JobService or running a foreground service instead? My code works on Android below 8 but it doesn't seems to work on O.

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceStarter" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

ServiceStarter (`extends BroadcastReceiver`):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    HTTPServerService.startService(context);
}
```

HTTPServerService.startService()

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, HTTPServerService.class));
```

I've looked on other similar questions but none seem to answer my specific problem. I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: did you figure out how to launch a long-running service at boot on Oreo ?

Comment: I tried the JobIntentService but not even that was completely reliable so we changed our flow to incorporate foreground service lauched from within the app thus eliminating the need for starting the service on boot.

Answer (score 4):

Answer

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, HTTPServerService.class));
} else {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, HTTPServerService.class));
}
```

+ permission in **`AndroidManifest.xml`**:

```
<manifest ...>
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
     ...
     <application ...>
     ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JobIntentService instead of regular service.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html

Comment: Unfortunately JobIntentService doesn't seem to work on Android 6... I call enqueueWork and onHandle never gets executed.

Comment: "This package is part of the Android support library which is no longer maintained. The support library has been superseded by AndroidX which is part of Jetpack."

Answer (score 0):

JobIntentService is working in 6 also I have tested.Please call service like below

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UploadService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.JOB_ID, ID);
        UploadService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
```

And in **UploadService** use below code

```
 public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
     enqueueWork(context,UploadService.class,JOB_ID, work);
}
```

Make sure that the Class name must be same in **enqueueWork** method

Comment: you aren't answering the author's question (**Start a background service on boot in Oreo**), you're talking about Android 6 and JobIntentService compatibility, you should have used comments

Comment: and what is `enqueueWork`? it doesn't exist

Comment: @user924 the static `enqueueWork()` is a convenience method in order to pass parameters cleanly. It's done like this with Activities and Fragments too. Just copy and paste the enqueueWork() method that Android dev provided into your JobIntentService. (your class would extend JobIntentService). I hope it helps.

Comment: "This package is part of the Android support library which is no longer maintained. The support library has been superseded by AndroidX which is part of Jetpack."

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, intentservice.class);
        context.startForegroundService(myIntent);        
    }
}
```

Comment: add some details also for better understanding